# Values not being transfered from JS to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a JS script of:

```
function addTasteingNote(userID,beerID)
    {
        //get values
        var note = $('#note1').val();


        var ajaxSettings = {
        type: "POST",
        url: "a.php",
        data: "u="+userID+"&b="+beerID+"&n="+note,
        success: function(data){


     } ,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert("error: " + error); }

    };          

        $.ajax(ajaxSettings);

        return false;
    }
```

and the php script  to add to the db is:

```
 <?php
    error_log("starting code"); 
    require_once('connect.inc.php');

            $u = $_GET['uID'];
            $b = $_GET['bID'];
            $n = $_GET['n'];

            //do some checks etc

            $db = new myConnectDB();
            error_log("Successfully created DB");   

            $query3 = "INSERT INTO x (userID,beerID,note) VALUES ($u, '$b', '$n')";

            error_log($query3);

            $result = $db->query($query3);
?>
```

The problem is that the error log shows nothing being put into the query:

```
[01-Nov-2013 23:40:29] Successfully created DB
[01-Nov-2013 23:40:29] INSERT INTO x (userID,beerID,note) VALUES (, '', '')
```

I have put alerts in the success of the ajax call, so I know that values are being passed through...

Comment: `data` should be an object, not a query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give data like

```
var ajaxSettings = {
    type: "POST",
    url: "a.php",
    data: {u:userID,b:beerID,n:note},
    success: function(data){


 }
```

`data` wont be and Query string,And since you are posting the values through ajax you need to get them via POST only like

```
$u = $_POST['u'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$n = $_POST['n'];
```

And your query should be like

```
$query3 = "INSERT INTO x (userID,beerID,note) VALUES ('".$u."', '".$b."', '".$n."')";
```

And Better to use **escape strings** with your `POST` variables to prevent from SQL injection.

Comment: what is your recommended way to escape?

Comment: To escape from `SQL injection` you need to escape either the `POST` or `GET` values while using with DB queries

Answer (score 0):

You are using post method so, you need to get data using `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET`

```
$u = $_REQUEST['u'];
$b = $_REQUEST['b'];
$n = $_REQUEST['n'];
```